# Retrieve camera intrinsics from PyRender PerspectiveVamera

Tags: computer-vision, pyrender

With PyRender, I'm trying to create a pointcloud from a depth map that I rendered using a [PerspectiveCamera](https://pyrender.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/pyrender.camera.PerspectiveCamera.html). For this, I will need the intrinsic parameters of the camera. Is there a straightforward way to retrieving those parameters? I tried the following, which clearly seems to be wrong, however I didn't find any other approaches yet:

```
f=(image_width/2)/math.tan(camera.yfov)
s=0
y0 = image_height/2
x0 = image_width/2

intrinsics = np.array(
[[f, s, x0],
[0, f, y0],
[0, 0, 1]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close enough. Your equation for f has the right shape. Minor issues.

You're

- mixing up x/y and width/height
- missing a /2 inside of the tan()
- and some -1 in the cx,cy which should exactly be (width-1)/2, (height-1)/2

And ignore the shearing, everyone else does.